# Unexpected undefined while import with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a problem that has never happened to me before: I'm compiling a little basic starter browser web app (with React) using Webpack + Babel 7.
I've got three different file:

1. `withAuth.js` The Auth High Order Component
2. `NavBar.js` The NavBar Component
3. `Login.js` The Login Form

If I import the `withAuth` HOC in the NavBar is everything alright, but if I import the `withAuth` component in the Login.js file it return `undefined`

```js
/** withAuth.js */

console.log('withAuth Loaded');

const withAuth = Child => ChildProps => (
    <AuthContext.Consumer>
        { authClient => <Child {...ChildProps} authClient={authClient} }
    </AuthContext.Consumer>
)

export { withAuth };


/** NavBar.js */
import { withAuth } from 'HOC/Auth';

console.log('NavBar Loaded', withAuth); // <- My HOC

const NavBarComponent = (authClient) => { /* ... My Code ... */ }

const NavBar = withAuth(NavBarComponent);

export default NavBar;


/** Login.js */
import { withAuth } from 'HOC/Auth';

console.log('Login Loaded', withAuth); // <- undefined ??

const LoginFormComponent = (authClient) => { /* ... My Code ... */ }

const LoginForm = withAuth(LoginFormComponent);
//                /|\
//                 |
//    Will produce an Error, withAuth is Undefined
```

This is my Webpack Configuration:

```js
/** webpack.config.js */

module.exports = {
    entry: { core: 'index.js' },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            HOC: './path/to/hoc/folder'
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    },
    plugins: [ /* Various Plugin */ ],
    module: {
       rules: [ /* My Rules */ ]
    }
}
```

Any one know why my HOC is `undefined`?

**Edit:**
I've placed Console Log in the tree file. The result are:

```
'Login Loaded' - undefined
'withAuth Loaded'
'NavBar Loaded' - function() { }
```

**Edit 2:**
This is the files structure:

```
app/
|-high-order-component/
| |-auth/
|   |-withAuth.js
|
|-layout-component/
| |-navbar/
|   |-index.js
|
|-pages/
  |-auth/
    |-login.js
```

Comment: Try using `path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/hoc/folder')` or any other variant that yields an absolute path

Comment: Hello Marco, are `withAuth.js`, `NavBar.js` and `Login.js in the same directory?

Comment: The alias.HOC property has been reduced here in StackOverflow to let you know that there is an alias pointing to withAuth. The three files are in separated folders. But I don't know why one component (the NavBar) load the HOC correctly and the other (Login) no...

Comment: There is no point in wondering about undefined behaviour. Did you try an absolute path?

Comment: Yes, even using absolute path to `withAuth.js` file the error still occurred. it seems that webpack calls the module before it is correctly loaded, but I don't know how it could be possible

Comment: I've got the error! It was a circular dependency that will break Webpack require function, I'll update the answer with some useful tips

Comment: You can answer your own question if you solved it. Can you elaborate what you mean by circular dependency, have you imported two components into each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Resolved**

After much testing and research throughout the afternoon I came to the solution of the problem. As I said in the question, mine is a larger project and I only partially wrote its structure because I thought the problem was located in those three files.

In reality, the problem was a Circular Dependency problem and not a Webpack configuration problem.
In my project I have a module called 'Route' that store all Path and all Component for Path, so I can build the React Router using Array Map function. That module has a function that allow me to Route through path and that can return me a path string to a Component.
My problem was due to the fact that this module is often called in the project and this has created a Circular Dependency.

Webpack doesn't show the Circular Dependency during compiling, but I found useful adding a plugin, called [CircualDependencyPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin). This plugin will break Webpack compiling when a Circual Dependency will be found.

Splitting the `Route` module into two files solved my problem.